# Stripe checkout and object-src

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, content-security-policy

I am trying out Stripe's checkout, but it has an error :

```
Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'object-src:'
```

got a [jsfidle](https://jsfiddle.net/4go287zc/) here, run it in Chrome and in the console tab you will see the error, how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: I just started getting this error in my app a few days ago. Defs coming from their js, not mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click that button you are going to Stripe's page, so this is not an issue for you to fix.

More generally the error appears to be a typo. CSP values should consist of a directive separated by a space from the permitted values and terminated with a semi colon.

For example `object-src 'self' *.youtube.com ;` will allow content in `<embed>` tags etc from the hosting site and from youtube.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/object-src

A single misformatted directive will show a console error but may not have any impact on the site. The `object-src` directive falls back to the `default-src` directive. If the default directive prevents a resource - perhaps a video - from loading but the malformed object directive allowed it then the video element would not run in the browser. However if this was the case you would also see a console error message saying that it had been blocked due to the default source settings

Comment: For accuracy, youtube actually uses iframes so the relevant directive is `frame-src` but the general point applies